# From where to download very big images for leaflet js

Tags: image, leaflet

Apologized for this post.

i want to download very big images for leaflet js. i search google but i found no very big which need lots of vertical and horizontal scroll to see full image. so if anyone know any url of big image photo which need lots of vertical and horizontal scroll to see full image then please share with me.

basically i am looking for big image to create small small tile from there as a result i could start my R&D code with leftlet js. basically i want to load my huge tile images using leaflet js api.

i found some big image url but those are not that much big. here are few which i found after searching google.

```
http://i2.liverpoolecho.co.uk/incoming/article9588426.ece/ALTERNATES/s1023/JS67516633.jpg

http://inapcache.boston.com/universal/site_graphics/blogs/bigpicture/natural_world_2011/bp1.jpg

http://photoblogstop.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Sierra_HDR_Panorama_DFX8048_2280x819_Q40_wm_mini.jpg
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, as far as I understand, you mean a big image in the terms of x/y number of pixels. Isn't the easiest way simply to make a photo and upload it somewhere you need? Contemporary cameras make really big images. 12mpix cameras make 5000 something by 3000 something, which should be enough for your purposes. Shouldn't it?

Comment: big image in terms of length and height which required huge scroll to see full images.

Comment: If a regular photos wouldn't be enough, [check this](http://gratisography.com/) or another web with extreme high-resolution photos. There should be some.

Comment: basically i am looking for image whose height and width will be huge big so people need to scroll lots in browser window to see the image fully.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.eso.org/public/images/eso1242a/), however I wonder how any browser would be able to deal with the images of such a size. Usually huge images are being split into many smaller parts and downloaded on demand.